# Elegant way to do a threaded .net application with multiple working threads, multuple source and sink threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've got an application where there are several threads that provide data, that needs to go through some heavy math. The math part needs a lot of initialization, afterwards it's pretty fast - as such I can't just spawn a thread every time I need to do the calculation, nor should every source thread have its own solver (there can be a LOT of such threads, beyond a certain point the memory requirements are obscene, and the overhead gets in the way or processing power).

I would like to use a following model: The data gathering and using threads would call to a single object, through one thread-safe interface function, like

```
public OutData DoMath(InData data) {...}
```

that would take care of the rest. This would involve finding a free worker thread (or waiting and blocking till one is available) passing by some means the data in a thread safe manner to one of the free worker threads, waiting (blocking) for it to do its job and gathering the result and returning it.

The worker thread(s) would then go into some sleep/blocked state, until a new input item would appear on its interface (or a command to clean up and die).

I know how to do this by means of various convoluted locks, queues and waits in a very horrible nasty way. I'm guessing there's a better, more elegant way.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good architecture for this?
2. Are there commonly used elegant means of doing this?

The target framework is .NET 4.5 or higher.

Thank you,

David

Comment: Use a list<> object for the processes to make the code simple.  If the count is less than X start a new process, otherwise, block until a process is available.  Design an architecture that is not convoluted, but uses waits.    Don't go into sleeps, instead use events.

Comment: Use TPL. And read [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The math part needs a lot of initialization, afterwards it's pretty fast - as such I can't just spawn a thread every time I need to do the calculation, nor should every source thread have its own solver (there can be a LOT of such threads, beyond a certain point the memory requirements are obscene, and the overhead gets in the way or processing power).

Sounds like a pool of lazy-initialized items. You can use a basic `BlockingCollection` for this, but I recommend overriding the default queue-like behavior with a stack-like behavior to avoid initializing contexts you may not ever need.

I'll call the expensive-to-initialize type `MathContext`:

```
private static readonly BlockingColleciton<Lazy<MathContext>> Pool;

static Constructor()
{
  Pool = new BlockingCollection<Lazy<MathContext>>(new ConcurrentStack<Lazy<MathContext>>());
  for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i) // or whatever you want your upper limit to be
    Pool.Add(new Lazy<MathContext>());
}
```

> This would involve finding a free worker thread (or waiting and blocking till one is available)

Actually, there's no point in using a worker thread here. Since your interface is synchronous, the calling thread can just do the work itself.

```
OutData DoMath(InData data)
{
  // First, take a context from the pool.
  var lazyContext = Pool.Take();
  try
  {
    // Initialize the context if necessary.
    var context = lazyContext.Value;

    return ... // Do the actual work.
  }
  finally
  {
    // Ensure the context is returned to the pool.
    Pool.Add(lazyContext);
  }
}
```

---

I also think you should check out the TPL Dataflow library. It would require a bit of code restructuring, but it sounds like it may be a good fit for your problem domain.

Comment: Thanks! That's actually true, when used like that it might work within the existing thread with the worker preinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate Task Parallel Library. It has a set of methods for creating and managing threads. And such classes as [ReaderWriterLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx), [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)
and their derivatives may help in synchronizing threads

Answer (score 0):

Don't use locks. This problem sounds nice for a proper nearly lock free approach.

I think what you need to look into is the [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Dd267312(v=VS.110).aspx). This class is a powerful collection for multiple consumers and producers. If you think about using it with [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=VS.110).aspx) you may want to look into writing your own [`Partitioner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd381768(v=vs.110).aspx) to get some more performance out of it. `Parallel` contains a couple of very nice methods if you only need a couple of threads for a relatively short time. That sounds like something you need to do. There are also overloads that provide initialization and finalization methods for each spawned thread along with passing thread local variables from one stage of the function to the next. That may really help you.

The general tips apply here of cause too. Try to split up your application in as may small parts as possible. That usually clears things up nicely and the ways how to do things become clearer.

All in all from what you told about the problem at hand I do not think that you need a lot of blocking synchronization. The `BlockingCollection` is only blocking the consumer threads until new data is ready to be consumed. And the producer if you limit the size...

I can't think of anything beyond that out of the top of my head. This is a very general question and without some specific issues it is hard to help beyond that.

I still hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! The BlockingCollections seems to fit the bill - I tried a simple solution where I create a "pool" of workers, take and put back from as needed through the interface function.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much described a thread pool - fortunately, there's quite a few simple APIs you can use for that. The simplest is probably

```
await Task.Run(() => DoMath(inData));
```

or just call `Task.Run(() => DoMath(inData)).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` if you don't mind blocking the requesting thread.

Instead of starting a whole new thread, it will simply borrow a thread from the .NET thread pool for the computation, and then return the result. Since you're doing almost pure CPU work, the thread pool will have only as much threads as you really need (that is, about the same (or double) amount as the number of CPU cores you have).

Using the `await` based version is a bit trickier - you need to ensure your whole call chain returns `Task`s - but it has a major advantage in avoiding the need to keep the calling thread alive while you wait for the results to be done. And even better, if you make sure the original thread is *also* a thread-pool thread, you don't even need the `Task.Run` - the threads will be balanced  automatically. Since you're only doing synchronous work anyway, this turns your whole problem into simply avoiding any manual `new Thread`, and using `Task.Run(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a pool of N such "math service objects" that are heavy. Then, guard usage of that pool with a `new SemaphoreSlim(N, N)`. Accessing those objects is then as easy as:

```
SemaphoreSlim sem = ...;
//...

await sem.WaitAsync();
var obj = TakeFromPool();
DoWork(obj);
Return(obj);
sem.Release();
```

You can vary this pattern in many ways. The core of it is the pool plus a semaphore that can be used to wait if the pool is empty at the time.